# Delta XML- Dita compare getting Caught com.deltaxml.dita.FilterProcessingException

Tags: java, xml, dita, deltaxml

I am using deltaxml for some time and it is working fine. But for a specific dita topics , I am getting these warnings in the logs:

```
WARNING: Caught com.deltaxml.dita.FilterProcessingException: Exception thrown when attempting to run the ‘input-a/9-dxp-9-cals-table-checker.xsl’ step (source: ‘/dita-xsl/cals-tables/cals-table-checker.xsl’) whilst performing DCE[BEINGPROCESSED: file:/home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/a-0-file-/regs/d ipflexcan3syn.dita, file:/home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/d ipflexcan3syn.dita.bak, file:/home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/d ipflexcan3syn.dita]
Feb 09, 2018 2:37:55 PM com.deltaxml.dita.ditabb ditaa
WARNING: Cannot find ids within file:/home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/d ipflexcan3syn.dita Cause: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/dipfl excan3syn.dita (No such file or directory)
Feb 09, 2018 2:37:55 PM com.deltaxml.dita.ditaq ditaa
WARNING: Cannot prepare topics for comparison. Cause: com.deltaxml.util.href.ditab: Cannot construct target (concerning hrefs file:/home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/d ipflexcan3syn.dita, file:/home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/d ipflexcan3syn.dita.dxml-p1)
Feb 09, 2018 2:38:02 PM com.deltaxml.dita.ditaq ditaa
WARNING: Skipping topicref /home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/dipfl excan3syn.dita. Cause: Cannot determine whether file:/home/nxf36037/crrbcompareissue/trydirecttmp5/b-0-file-/regs/d ipflexcan3syn.dita contains change.
```

I am not able to find the cause of this issue, I have tried almost all the arguments which I felt could be the cause.
The command line I am using is:

```
java -jar /pkg/deltaxml-dita-/2017.09.21/lib/deltaxml-dita.jar compare mts B1518165232953/dipflexcan3syn/specsource/maps/dipflexcan3synbg .ditamap B1518165232953/dipflexcan3syn/specsource/maps/dipflexcan3syn_bg .ditamap output-format=dita-markup map-result-structure=map-pair map-result-origin=B trydirecttmp5
```

I have also checked the dita files, they gets validated and there are no errors. Could you please help here?

Answer (score 1):

The schematron code at:  https://github.com/nigelwhitaker/cals-table-schematron can be used to detect and report, in a fairly user-friendly manner, table validation issues, either inside an editor or using the schematron skeleton.

As discussed with Mohit over in https://github.com/nigelwhitaker/cals-table-schematron/issues/4  it does however depend on XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 features and therefore is not suitable for all schematron systems.